# Javascript photoshop data sets

Tags: javascript, variables, text, photoshop, text-size

I have to create a series of images in photoshop with a basic background with a text in the middle, which varies according to a data set. With Photoshop you can set variables and data sets, and for this I have no problems. But I would like that the size of the text were to vary depending on the number of characters in a word, so it can fill with text almost any size. The images must have the usual name of the word that is printed on 'image.
Sorry for my language i'm not english native!

[examples of two images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC5xJ.jpg)

Comment: If you are using image, it will not be possible. You need to have a separate background color from the text

Comment: I tried only with photoshop variables, creating a layer and applying an external data set (text file or csv).
The problem is that when I have a long word, and the text ends so out of the image.
So I wish that the text size is proportionate to the number of letters.